# tensorflow making an op for gpu usage -- demo app doesn't work

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm using tensorflow and after creating the following files I get the error below. I suspect I'm supplying the wrong kind of input, but I don't know how to change it to the proper representation.

dijkstra.py :

```
    self.maze = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64], dtype=tf.int32), name="grid")

    print  self.maze
    if True : 
        self.grid_module = tf.load_op_library('d_grid_gpu.so')
        with tf.Session('') as sess:
            sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
            self.output = self.grid_module.grid_gpu(
                    self.maze

                ).eval()
```

d_grid_gpu.cc :

```
    #include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
    #include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"

    using namespace tensorflow;

    REGISTER_OP("GridGpu").Input("grid: int32").Output("prev: int32");    

        void run( int * in);

    class DGridGpuOp : public OpKernel {
      public:
      explicit DGridGpuOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {


      }

      void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {


        Tensor* prev_tensor = NULL;

        Tensor grid_tensor = context->input(0);

        auto grid = grid_tensor.flat<int32>();    


        OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(
                                     0, 
                                     TensorShape({64}), &prev_tensor));

        auto prev = prev_tensor->template flat<int32>();


        run(grid.data());//


      }

    };

    REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("GridGpu").Device(DEVICE_GPU), DGridGpuOp);
```

d_grid_gpu.cu.cc :

```
    #if GOOGLE_CUDA
    #define EIGEN_USE_GPU
    #include "third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"

    #include <stdio.h>
    #define SIZE    10

        __global__ void VectorAdd(  int *in,  int n)
        {
            int i = threadIdx.x;

            if (i < n)
                in[i] = in[i] + i;
        }


        void run( int * in){

            VectorAdd<<< 1, SIZE >>>(  in,  SIZE);

            /* 
            //these lines cause the segfault
            //for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i ++) {
            //    printf("%i, " , in[i]);
            //}
            */
        }


    #endif
```

build script :

```
    TF_INC=$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())')


    nvcc -std=c++11 -c -o d_grid_gpu.cu.o d_grid_gpu.cu.cc \
    -I $TF_INC -D GOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC --expt-relaxed-constexpr

    g++ -std=c++11 -shared -o d_grid_gpu.so d_grid_gpu.cc \
    d_grid_gpu.cu.o -I $TF_INC -fPIC -lcudart -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

**edit** : I removed the old output.

I tried the 'add_one' op (from the TF howto page) and I think I got it to work. This leads me to believe my installation is OK. This example compiles. I just cannot get the registration right I guess -- or something. Any help would be welcome.

**edit**: I reinstalled tensorflow and now the error is a little different

```
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
    simple dijkstra for tensorflow
    <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7fdec57c1b50>
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:951] Found device 0 with properties: 
    name: GeForce GTX 850M
    major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.9015
    pciBusID 0000:0a:00.0
    Total memory: 3.95GiB
    Free memory: 3.64GiB
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:972] DMA: 0 
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] 0:   Y 
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 850M, pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test_op.py", line 45, in <module>
        d.eval()
      File "/home/dave/workspace/awesome-tf/test_gpu/dijkstra.py", line 57, in eval
        self.maze
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 559, in eval
        return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3761, in _eval_using_default_session
        return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 717, in run
        run_metadata_ptr)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 915, in _run
        feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _do_run
        target_list, options, run_metadata)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 985, in _do_call
        raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value grid
         [[Node: grid/read = Identity[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@grid"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](grid)]]

    Caused by op u'grid/read', defined at:
      File "test_op.py", line 45, in <module>
        d.eval()
      File "/home/dave/workspace/awesome-tf/test_gpu/dijkstra.py", line 50, in eval
        self.maze = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64], dtype=tf.int32), name="grid")
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 215, in __init__
        dtype=dtype)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 327, in _init_from_args
        self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1128, in identity
        result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Identity", input=input, name=name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 749, in apply_op
        op_def=op_def)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2380, in create_op
        original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1298, in __init__
        self._traceback = _extract_stack()

    FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value grid
         [[Node: grid/read = Identity[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@grid"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](grid)]]
```

sometimes this is my output:

```
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
    simple dijkstra for tensorflow
    <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7fba5d0dafd0>
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:951] Found device 0 with properties: 
    name: GeForce GTX 850M
    major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.9015
    pciBusID 0000:0a:00.0
    Total memory: 3.95GiB
    Free memory: 3.67GiB
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:972] DMA: 0 
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] 0:   Y 
    I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 850M, pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0)
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is the case when I use `initialize_all_variables()`

Comment: I also have a similar question asked here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183189/trouble-compiling-with-custom-tensorflow-gpu-op

Comment: so, I thought I was being clear but maybe I wasn't. I can actually get the AddOneKernel program for the GPU to work. A link to that is here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html#gpu-support and here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/adding_an_op/cuda_op_kernel.cu.cc What I find is that though I can get this op to work, I cannot get my own op to work. For example, if I replace `self.maze` with a set of numbers like `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]` I get a segmentaion fault. I thought `tf.Variable(...)` would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `tf.initialize_all_variables` to initialize, for instance:

`with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())`

Comment: where would I put that? Because I put it just after the `tf.Variable(...)` line and it does nothing. I get the same error for the most part.

Comment: Updated answer. You have to run that before you run anything else in the session.

Comment: Now I get a segmentation fault. That is the same output as if I used `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` as the value for `self.maze`. I have edited the question a little bit and included the output from the segfault.

Comment: this is important. The essential part for me is that the segfault is not from cuda code, but c code in the run() method

Comment: Good, you're progressing! What does gdb tell you? (You may want to build with `-c dbg`)